# How to skip a transaction in replicate(Target system) in Goldengate oracle

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

Requirement:

Source table contains 5 columns. We are replicating 3 columns on target out of 5.
SEQ_ID is additional column on target.

When update operation is performed on columns which are not in target table,SEQ_ID is increased.
SEQ_ID should increase only when update performed on columns which are present on target.

Enabling unconditional supplemental table level logging on selected columns(ID,AGE,COL1) to be replicated:

Source:
Table name: Test1(ID,AGE,COL1,COL2,COL3)

Target:
Table name: Test1(ID,AGE,COL1,SEQ_ID)

We created a sequence to increse the SEQ_ID when a insert or update happens.

Scenario :
If insert or update happens on source table on these columns (ID,AGE,COL1)  SEQ_ID is incresed,
and if update happens on others columns(COL2,COL3)  SEQ_ID is also getting incremented.

Our Requirement is when update happens on others columns(COL2,COL3) ,SEQ_ID should not get incrementd.
I want to skip the transaction of updates happening on columns(COL2,COL3) .

Source:
Primary extract test_e1
EXTRACT  TEST_e1
USERID DBTUAT_GG,PASSWORD dbt_1234
EXTTRAIL /DB_TRACK_GG/GGS/dirdat/dd
GETUPDATEBEFORES
--IGNOREUPDATES
--IGNOREDELETES
NOCOMPRESSUPDATES
TABLE HARI.TEST1,COLS(ID,AGE,COL1),FILTER (ON UPDATE,IGNORE UPDATE, @STREQ(before.AGE, AGE) = 0);

Datapump test_p1:
EXTRACT TEST_P1
USERID DBTUAT_GG,PASSWORD dbt_1234
RMTHOST 10.24.187.235, MGRPORT 7809,
RMTTRAIL /Trail_files/tt
--PASSTHRU
TABLE DBTUAT_GG.TEST1;

Target:
Target Repicat file:
Edit param test_r

REPLICAT TEST_R
USERID GGPROD,PASSWORD GGPROD_123
SOURCEDEFS ./dirsql/def32.sql
HANDLECOLLISIONS
IGNOREDELETES
INSERTMISSINGUPDATES
MAP HARI.TEST1, TARGET HARI.TEST1, &
SQLEXEC (ID test_num,QUERY "select GGPROD.test_seq.NEXTVAL test_val from dual", NOPARAMS), &
COLMAP(USEDEFAULTS,SEQ_ID=test_num.test_val);

Kindly suggest any possible solutions .

Answer (score 0):

First note: you don't need USERID and PASSWORD in the Pump PRM. The Pump process does not connect to any database.

Actually you have already achieved your goal. You are only replicating the data when AGE is modified. There is a FILTER clause in the Extract PRM file. The ID column should not get changed since this is the PK. The only problem is that your are increasing the SEQ_ID if a delete gets replicated.

Something like that should work:

```
ALLOWDUPTARGETMAP

IGNOREDELETES
-- just inserts and updates that change COL1
MAP HARI.TEST1, TARGET HARI.TEST1, & 
  SQLEXEC (ID test_num,QUERY "select GGPROD.test_seq.NEXTVAL test_val from dual", NOPARAMS), & 
  COLMAP(USEDEFAULTS, SEQ_ID = test_num.test_val);

-- just replicate the delete operations
GETDELETES
IGNOREINSERTS
IGNOREUPDATES
MAP HARI.TEST1, TARGET HARI.TEST1;
GETINSERTS
GETUPDATES
```